# Getting Infrastructure metrics from AWS Batch to DataDog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, datadog, aws-batch

Is there a direct integration point or a connector to integrate an AWS Batch job with DataDog? To retrieve the logs and infrastructure metrics?

So far what I came across was the DataDog forwarder which can forward the logs to DataDog from Cloudwatch but nothing for Infrastructure metrics?

Comment: Depends on the computation environment you use. There should be integration guides for both EC2 and ECS - https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_web_services/?tab=roledelegation

Comment: @TomášLinhart I am using EC2 as the compute env. So are you suggesting I pass the Datadog agent to the java process at the start?

Comment: I'm suggesting you read the documentation and follow the step-by-step guide there ;-)

Comment: @TomášLinhart i dont see any docs regarding aws batch. waste of time

Comment: You were talking about _infrastructure metrics_, right? I guess that translates to ECS task or EC2 metrics.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1522

Comment: How about container metrics? e.g. memory usage. Do you have a recomendation for that? @TomášLinhart

Comment: @AnugerahErlaut take a look at [Container Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-container-insights.html).